# Export-Csv doesn't create a file

Tags: powershell, csv, export, export-to-csv

I need to export CSV data to a CSV file. I have this code:

```
$Input | where {$AnotherFile.userPrincipalName -notcontains $_.login} |
    Export-Csv -Path "$PSScriptRoot + \output.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

In this case, the script ends with this error: Part of path "*script root* + \output.csv was not found". The *script root* is correctly written full path to the folder, where the script is located.

I tried also this:

```
$Input | where {$AnotherFile.userPrincipalName -notcontains $_.login} |
    Export-Csv -Path "output.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

In this case, the script seems to finish smoothly (no error is displayed), but the file is not created. I even tried search the disk, if it wasn't created in another directory.

This works perfectly correct:

```
$Input | where {$File.userPrincipalName -notcontains $_.login}
```

In this case I get precisely all the data I want, listed on the screen. Which is nice, but useless. What error do I make in the `Export-Csv` cmdlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path for CSV `"$PSScriptRoot + \output.csv"` will be evaluated into `C:\folder + \output.csv` which is likely not your intention.

Remove the spaces and `+` so it it's just: `"$PSScriptRoot\output.csv"` this will evaluate to `C:\folder\output.csv`.

```
$Input | where {$AnotherFile.userPrincipalName -notcontains $_.login} | Export-Csv -Path "$PSScriptRoot\output.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it must be some "stupid" thing, I was just not able to figure it out :-)